# Logstash Map parsing error

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash

When I am trying to use logstash to read through a configuration file, I come up with map parsing error.

> :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-2016.06.07", "type"=>"txt",
>   "id"=>nil, "status"=>400,
>   "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "r eason"=>"Failed to
>   parse mapping [*default*]: Mapping definition for [data] has
>   unsupported parameters: [ignore_above : 1024]",
>   "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"Mapping
>   definition for [data] has unsupported para meters: [ignore_above :
>   1024]"}}}}, :level=>:warn}←[0m

A sample line of my data is like that:

```
167.57.21.143 2016-05-26 00:00:12 cms-corp-aeis-prd.server.ab.org.au:32028 POST /aeis/7_0_0/aeis/timecapture.do HTTP/1.1 200 109 JOvopGXLSq4o-tWMV8Oj-6aDSILdcL3jd9bsyUiaI6a3vFO5o7dm!449867976!1464191968906 3eec121a91ac23b8:2be0a5e5:1533d1684e1:-7f72-00000000005fc371 4109 1464192012809 0.238
```

**And when I run the file, it did give out the grok parse result, even have mapping error**

```
{
                                       "message" => "167.57.21.143 2016-05-26 00:00:12 cms-corp-aeis-prd.server.ab.org.au:32028 POST /aeis/7_0_0/aeis/timecapture.do\tHTTP/1.1 200 109 JOvopGXLSq4o-tWMV8Oj-6aDSILdcL3jd9bsyUiaI6a3vFO5o7dm!449867976!1464191968906 3eec121a91ac23b8:2be0a5e5:1533d1684e1:-7f72-00000000005fc371 4109 1464192012809 0.238\r",
                                      "@version" => "1",
                                    "@timestamp" => "2016-06-07T17:03:20.752Z",
                                          "path" => "C:\\HA\\accesslog\\trial.log",
                                          "host" => "WIN-07LLQEN2SJB",
                                          "type" => "txt",
                                    "ClientAddr" => "167.57.21.143",
                                          "date" => "2016-05-26",
                                          "time" => "00:00:12",
           "x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.VirtualHost" => "cms-corp-aeis-prd.server.ab.org.au:32028",
                                     "cs-method" => "POST",
                                   "cs-uri-stem" => "/aeis/7_0_0/aeis/timecapture.do",
              "x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.Protocol" => "HTTP/1.1",
                                     "sc-status" => "200",
                                         "bytes" => "109",
    "x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.RequestedSessionId" => "JOvopGXLSq4o-tWMV8Oj-6aDSILdcL3jd9bsyUiaI6a3vFO5o7dm!449867976!1464191968906",
                  "x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.Ecid" => "3eec121a91ac23b8:2be0a5e5:1533d1684e1:-7f72-00000000005fc371",
              "x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.ThreadId" => "4109",
                 "x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.EndTs" => "1464192012809",
                                    "time-taken" => "0.238" }
```

Here is my logstash.conf

```
input{
    stdin{}
    file{
        type => "txt"
        path => "C:\HA\accesslog\trial.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
filter{
    grok{
    match => {"message" => ["%{IP:ClientAddr}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:date}%{SPACE}%{TIME:time}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.VirtualHost}%{SPACE}%{WORD:cs-method}%{SPACE}%{PATH:cs-uri-stem}%{SPACE}%{PROG:x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.Protocol}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:sc-status}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:bytes}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.RequestedSessionId}%{SPACE}%{PROG:x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.Ecid}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.ThreadId}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.EndTs}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:time-taken}"]}
        }

}
output{
    elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }   
}
```

I would like to ask if anyone have any methods to solve the issues.
Great thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your logstash config?

Comment: Sure, I have added it back